# Please explain Java inheritance in this case

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and can't understand some tricks of inheritance.
Example:

- we have a class `Animal`;
- we have a class `Cat`, extends `Animal`;
- we have a class `Tiger`, extends `Cat`;

Questions:

1) Why Cat uses Tigers method?
See below example of "make_a_sound" method. It's from Tiger, but Cat can use it.

2) Why Cat, can not see any properties of Tiger?
Cat can use method "make_a_sound" of Tiger, but can not see its properties... quite strange.

Thanks,
Gennadiy

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(string[] args) {

        Cat cat = new Tiger();

        // The result is from Tiger class: A tiger says RRRRR & new tiger property
        // Why???
        cat.make_a_sound();

        // Only cat's and Animal's properties are visible. No Tiger's properties
        System.out.println(cat.this_is_a_cat);
    }

    // Base class
    public class Animal {
        public String this_is_an_animal = "Animal";

        public void make_a_sound() {
            System.out.Printf("I'm an animal");
        }
    }

    // Extends base class
    public class Cat extends Animal {
        public String this_is_a_Cat = "Hi, I'm a cat";

        public void make_a_sound() {
            System.out.Printf("A cat says meey");
        }
    }

    // Extends prev. class
    public class Tiger extends Cat {
        public String this_is_a_Tiger = "Tiger";

        public void make_a_sound() {
            System.out.Println("A tiger says RRRRRR");

            this_is_a_Tiger = "new tiger property";
            System.out.println(new_tiger_property);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Q1: Due to polymorphic behavior because of this: `Cat cat = new Tiger();`

Comment: Sure, but do you have any links to Videos with detailed description? I just wanna understand the depth of this.

Comment: 1. It uses a method declared in its own class `Cat`, that is overridden in `Tiger`. 2. Because a `Tiger` is a `Cat` but a `Cat isn't necessarily a `Tiger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `cat` as type `Cat`. That means `cat` can do anything that any other `Cat` can do.  The `Animal` object does define the `make_a_sound` function so it's available to all `Animal` instances. When you run your code, the variable `cat` points to a `Tiger` instance so when `make_a_sound` is called, it's the one in `Tiger` that runs. That's the whole point of inheritance.

For your second question, `cat` is of type `Cat` so you can only do things with it that you can do with any `Cat` object. Since `this_is_a_Tiger` is not something every `Cat` object has, it is not available to `cat` even though `cat` really points to a `Tiger`.

But you could do this:

```
if (cat instanceof Tiger) {
   Tiger tiger = (Tiger)cat;
   System.out.println(tiger.this_is_a_Tiger);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why Cat uses Tigers method? See below example of "make_a_sound" method. It's from Tiger, but Cat can use it.

Answer) Because when you say Cat cat = new Tiger() you are not saying any cat,you are saying you want sound of the Tiger and not any generic cat.Tiger is using cat's "make_a_sound" method by over riding the implementation by the Tigers sound.

if you had not overriden tigers "make_a_sound" method then the Cat's "make_a_sound" method will be called.You can try it out by saying super().make_a_sound in Tiger class or removing implementation of this method.

2) Why Cat, can not see any properties of Tiger? Cat can use method "make_a_sound" of Tiger, but can not see its properties... quite strange.

Answer) If parents classes would know everything about child class then OOPS will be broken.In OOPS each class should only know about what it does and nothing else.It does not care of other class responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

This link could give you some concept regarding **Overriding** in Java: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-in-java/

For simplicity, `Overriding` only take effective on methods (regarding Question 1), but not on field variables (regarding Question 2).